# make_shared how to use non default memory management

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, make-shared

I have a question about the standard..

So let's say I have pools that manage my memory allocation..

I wanted to use shared_ptr and checked out the API..

As expected, I see that for shared_ptr I control the allocation of the pointer and I can give it a dealloction function, Perfect!!

Now I've watched STL's lectures and I find that maked_shared is more memory efficient (since it  can allocate the control block and ptr at the same place)
Obviously I went straight away to the maked_shared api, only to find out that make_shared is forcing me to use new/delete only..
So Questions would be:

1. Am I correct? only new/delete?
2. If so, Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::allocate_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared)?

Comment: @Daniel it would appear so :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use [`std::allocate_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared) which allows you to use your own allocator.